# How does array assignment work within a python function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, assignment-operator

I'm confused by the following example.  Let `a=[1]` be a python list and try to write a function which re-assigns the list such that we will have `a=[2]` after running the function.

A simple function which works is

```
def works1(arr):
    arr[0]=2
```

or another example is

```
def works2(arr):
    arr[0]=2*arr[0]
```

Either does what I would want when running `works1(a)` or `works2(a)`: both set `a=[2]`.

However, something like the following which tries to re-assign the entire array at once, rather than doing it component-by-component, will fail.

```
def fails1(arr):
    arr=[2*x for x in arr]
```

Running `fails1(a)` does not reassign `a`, which is still given by `a=[1]`.

Could someone please explain this behavior or point me to where in the documentation I should be looking to understand the above?

Edit: For context, if helpful, I was trying to understand why the `mergeSort` code at [this site](https://runestone.academy/runestone/books/published/pythonds/SortSearch/TheMergeSort.html) was able to re-assign an externally defined list.  Initially thought that `alist` within that `mergeSort` code should be a local variable.

Comment: `arr` is a local variable. When you assign it, it no longer contains a reference to the original list.

Comment: You can use slice assignment to update the list: `arr[:] = [2*x for x in arr]`

Comment: Also `a != arr`. `a[0]` just mutates state on an object, completely different from a reassignment that takes `a` and points it to an entirely different, newly allocated list. The original variable in the calling scope won't be affected by such a reassignment.

Comment: Ah sorry I had a typo in both `works1` and `works2`: the previous `a` instances should have been `arr`'s.  But @Barmar, yes exactly, I was actually confused why the `works1` and `works2` functions accomplish what I want at all, since I thought they'd just be assigning values to a local variable.  I see now that since I did not actually initialize what `arr` is in either of these cases, they cannot be making a new local variable named `arr`, unlike `fails1`.

Comment: @ggorlen thanks, that was just a typo on my part. Should have had `arr`'s where there were `a`'s in `works1` and `works2`.  But I think I understand now: could you tell me if my comment above is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arr` is a reference to a list object

When you write `arr[0]=1` you change the element in this referenced object.
But when you write `arr=[..new list..]` you just make `arr` refer to a new object, and it does not affect previous object.

Comment: Cool, yeah that's what I came to understand from the comments above, thanks.  I was thought initially that having `arr[0]=1` within a function also would initialize `arr` as a local variable, but I see that is incorrect now.